# C coding, unexpected behaviour when comparing float value

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm getting an unexpected behaviour when comparing a float value, I understand that floats could have rounding precission issues but here numbers are quite specific to present those issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float alpha = 0.0f;
    int finish = 0;

    while (finish == 0)
    {
        alpha += 0.05f;

        if (alpha > 1.0f)
        {
            printf("%f", alpha);    // Expected result: 1.05f, actual result: 1.0f
            finish = 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actually, condition enters when alpha = 1.0f. Can't understand that behaviour...

I'm compiling with MinGW (GCC 5.3.0) on Windows 10 (tested on 32bit and 64bit), Intel i5 processors.

Comment: If you were to print `alpha` with more significant digits (e.g. `printf("%.7f\n", alpha);`) then you would immediately see the problem: http://ideone.com/zwQW7e.

Comment: You have to know whether the constant for 0.05f is slightly smaller or slightly larger than the infinite bit stream that would represent 0.05 exactly.  Presumably, it is slightly larger.

Comment: Check this out (it's what I used to build my answer):http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Comment: @Olaf, good duplicate but sometimes it's nice to explain the result in a particular case (whilst compiling some code).

Comment: @Bathsheba: The explanation is in the dup. Askers are expected to be able to understand such basics and apply them to their situation if they are that obvious as here.

Comment: @Olaf: I think I need to flatter your intelligence here. Indeed to you it is obvious. I tend to answer the well-written floating point questions.

Comment: @Ray: Please study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @Bathsheba: Considering the amount of "do my homework" and "what does operator/statement xyx mean" questions, you are right. There are indeed only few C questions which are no dups. Problem is more to find the dups, as noobs are very creative using wrong/missleading phrases. Oh, and we should expect some reason from posters, too. Without that they won't get anywhere in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Restricting the answer if I may to IEEE754 floating point).

There is no such `float` as `0.05`. The *nearest* number representable to that is

`0.0500000007450580596923828125`

So what is happening, is that *slightly* larger values than what you think are added to `alpha`, which is enough to *just* push it over the `1.0f` mark (which, out of interest, *can* be represented exactly.)

The default formatting in `print` is rounding that slightly greater than `1.0f` number back to `1.0f`.

In summary, all this is due to binary floating point not having, in general, an exact decimal representation.

Comment: I disagree, although the OP would be advised to study the duplicate. Even armed with the floating point knowledge, it's nice to have an explanation for this particular case. (For what it's worth I probably close 2 or 3 floating point questions as duplicated to the one you've identified per week.)